# Can not get child when getting Context in extends ImageView class

Tags: android, imageview, children

I got an extends ImageView class. (A class that extends ImageView, and not a layout ImageView)
In a app I am developing I am trying to get Child from a GridView using:

```
MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass someThing =(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass)gridViewIGetTheChildFrom.getChildAt(some int);
```

If I call this on any of my interface defined voids this does what I want it to.

But I want to call this when the class is called, and therefore I call it when I get Context like so:

```
public ImageCell (Context context) {
super (context);
MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass upe =(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass)gridViewIGetTheChildFrom.getChildAt(some int);}
```

This causes a crash with a NullPointerException and with this as "Caused By" in my logCat.

```
11-19 22:00:48.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6252):     at my.package.name.MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass.<init>(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass.java:57)
```

Why am I not able to get the child of the GridView? I have tried delaying with a Thread with no luck, and calling another void causes the same crash. 
How can I get the child?

Comment: Why are you trying to get it manually, why don't you use your `Adapter`?

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins I allready have an Adapter for the GridView, but I am makeing a game where I need to get it in tha class itself. Otherwise my work the last mounth would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer actually suggests your `gridViewIGetTheChildFrom` object is null whilst trying to call a method on it.

`Log` that `gridViewIGetTheChildFrom` is actually not null and then go from there.

Although I would look at a better way of passing your object around, through an interface/delegate/callback is the recommended way normally.